# »Hat eventuell noch einer eine ...?«

Tags: phrase, word-order, colloquial, question

Someone at work wrote a sentence. Im pasting you the beginning:

> Hat eventuell noch einer eine unbenutzte ...?

And two questions assault my mind:

1. Is *einer* just another way of saying *jemand?* Is that official German? Or just street language?
2. How about the word order? I thought all this time that in a question the first word should be the verb and the second the subject, but in this sentence *eventuell noch* seems to have slipped into that position. Why is that?

Comment: ein Mensch = einer

Comment: Please ask only one thing at a time. For a reason, have a look at the current answers: @Janka has written an [excellent explanation](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/34485/5999) for item 2 in your list of doubts, but I cannot upvote it as it stands, because it answers only half of your question ... because your question is actually two questions.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Then vote to close, since closing early prevents forking answers, which make it hard to close it later.

Comment: @userunknown: Done. Although I find the close reasons somewhat dissatisfying. It's not "unclear what [the OP is] asking", it's very clear. It's so clear that two questions can be made out of it, each of which will still be clear about what the OP is asking. I used "too broad", although that's really unspecific, too.

Comment: @Iris:  Hat eventuell noch einer eine unbenutze Kopfhörerbuchse? (ein Verstärker = einer).

Comment: Es ist unklar, für welche Frage die Akzeptiertmarkierung vergeben wird, bzw. welche der zwei Fragen die Moderatoren löschen sollen, damit sie in separat gestellt wird.. Optimal passt die Beschreibung nicht, stimme ich zu, aber am besten von den zur Auswahl stehenden.

Comment: @userunknown, würde ich anders interpretieren. Hat noch ein Mensch /jemand eine unbenutze Kopfhörernuche (an seinem Verstärker)?

Comment: @Iris: Und wenn da nur ein Mensch mit 7 Verstärkern ist?

Comment: @userunknown, dann würde ich ganz anders fragen, nämlich:  Hast du an/Gibt es an einem noch einen unbenutzte Kopfhörerbuchse?

Answer (score 4):

*Einer* indeed is colloquial for *jemand*. The word order is the example is covered by the flexibility of word order in German, and the phrase *eventuell noch* has been inserted for politeness.

Answer (score 2):

The correct form of this sentence would be:

> Hat eventuell noch **einer von euch** ein unbenutztes Taschentuch?

1. JEMAND
   "Einer/eine von euch" is more specific than "jemand". It
   is often abbreviated to "einer/eine".
2. WORD ORDER
   The first word in a question without interrogative
   pronoun is the finite verb, the subject follows. The subject can be
   composed of two or more words. The positioning of the words defines
   the meaning of the sentence:

> Hat **eventuell noch einer** ein unbenutztes Taschentuch?

*maybe someone else*

> Hat einer eventuell **noch ein** unbenutztes **Taschentuch**?

*maybe another kleenex* / *maybe a kleenex left*

> Hat einer eventuell ein **noch unbenutztes** Taschentuch?

*yet unused*

> Hat einer ein **eventuell noch unbenutztes** Taschentuch?

*eventually yet unused*

Comment: I see how the change of order of words changed the meaning, but... if the rule is that "First the finite verb, and then the subject follow", does that mean that `eventuell noch` belong to the subject?

Comment: Yes, it does. Another example: "**Der** an vielen Tagen der Woche stark alkoholisierte **Mann** hatte kaum Freunde." It's easier to recognize as part of the subject if the subject has an article. "einer von euch" unfortunately hasn't.

Comment: Well, that last example uses an subordinate sentence, so it is somehow different... but if you say that `eventueller noch` belongs to the subject, I will believe you (even though `eventuell` sounds really like **not** a part of the subject...) Thanks!

Comment: There is no subordinate clause in the last example. It would have if I said: Der Mann, *der* an vielen Tagen der Woche stark alkoholisiert *war*, hatte kaum Freunde.

Comment: The subject itself is an article plus a noun or any pronoun. "Eventually" is, of course, a modal adverb. But everything that specifies the subject, is a specifying **addition** to the subject and as such becomes part of it, at least in regard to the word order.

Comment: I didnt see "Eventually" like something that specifies the subject really. It was more like something that specified the general sentence, but I guess I have to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

"Second position" does not mean it has to be the second word. Neither does "first position" mean it has to be the first word. There can be always stray words explaining the verb, nouns or the sentence as a whole.

> »Vielleicht hat auch noch einer eine unbenutzte Fahrkarte?« fragte der Schaffner.

*“Maybe someone even has an unused ticket?”* the conductor asked.

Comment: Your example isn't clarifying, because it is a question only by intonation. The finite verb has to be in second position here and it is - in your example - the second word....